# Set variables in Javascript job entry at root level

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I need to set variables in root scope in one job to be used in a different job. The first job has a Javascript job entry, with the statements:

```
parent_job.setVariable("customers_full_path", "C:\\customers22.csv", "r");
true;
```

But the compilation fails with:

> Couldn't compile javascript:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method
>   org.pentaho.di.job.Job.setVariable(string,string,string). (#2)

How to set a variable at root level in a Javascript job entry?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the passive agressive but:

[image]

I don't know if you are new to Pentaho but, the most common mistake for new users, with previous knowledge of programming, is to be sort of 'addicted' to know methods, as such you are using JavaScript for a functionality that is built in the tool. Both Transformations(KTR) and JOBs(KJB) have a similar step, you can better manipulate this in a KTR.

JavaScript steps slow down the flow considerably, so try to stay away from those as much as possible.

EDIT:

Reading [This article](https://wiki.pentaho.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4358187), seems the only thing you're doing wrong is the actual syntax of the command..
Correct usage :

parent_job.setVariable("Desired Value", [name_of_variable]);

The command you described has 3 parameters, when it should be 2. If you have more than 1 variable you need to set, use 3 times the command. Try it out see if it works.

Comment: Christian, the code in the question is a simplification of the real case where I have several nested `if/else` and that I cannot solve with `Set Variables`. Do you know how to set a variable at root scope in a Javascript job entry?

Comment: Edited my answer with possible new solution.

Comment: Then the only solution i see is, since you're using JavaScript for multiple IF tests, is to use this script in a transformation, and use the result in a Set Variables Step, using the 'Valid in the Root Job' option. Since in JavaScript you can only set variables in _entry_(current Job) or pentaho_job (parent job).

Comment: This is how I solved it, I created a function `getRoot()` in the script to return the root, then I do a loop `var parent = parent_job.getParentJob();` until parent is null, that means I'm in the root.
`